# Doing form events with Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have custom html5 error message for input, which changes validation error text in chrome.

```
<input
   oninvalid="setCustomValidity('It's custom message!')"
   onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
```

How can I do this with Angular directive?

**Updated**

Let's say, I want type `<input custom-validity>` instead of this.

Comment: I don't it is the angular way to rely on browser implementation, like you do when using customValidity.

Comment: Hey, let's say I want type `<input custom-validity>` instead of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can learn all about doing form validation the Angular way in their [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

You don't need to create your own directives, because angular already has great form validation support built in.

Below is an example how to use the $dirty and $invalid attributes to show or hide validation messages. 'dirty' means that the form has been modified by the user.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <p>
        <label>Name
            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" required>
            <span ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && myForm.name.$dirty">
                Name required
            </span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid && myForm.email.$dirty">
                Put a valid email
            </span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
  </form>
</div>
```

You can also style the valid/invalid fields using a style rule like this:

```
form input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty { ... }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but I'm using default HTML5 validation, and this code is for the browser bubble which appears when error occurs. this code changes default text for the bubble. So I don't need `ng validation` at this time.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that it is not in the spirit of angular to rely on html5 form validation. Instead, angular allows you to implement your own form validation, which will be consistent across browsers. From my example above you could style the messages as text bubbles with your own css or perhaps a css-framework like bootstrap.